# Set Textarea cursor to start of textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to this. 
I recently started learning HTML/JavaScript/PHP.

I have created a form that a user can type information into and update any changes they have made.

I used the Textarea as the information being requested is quite large. 
When someone wants to update the information they entered before, a PHP code I wrote displays the information previously written:

```
  <textarea class="datainput" row="4" cols="60"><?php echo $dataInput['data_input'];?></textarea>
```

All works fine except, the cursor is not in a fixed position at the start when the user first enters the information.

It appears in the middle of the first row of the Textarea.

How do I set the cursor position to the top left corner (start)?

Comment: Are you sure your HTML looks exactly like that? You haven't reformatted it for the question?

Comment: @Quentin it looks exactly like that.

Comment: If it looks like that, and the user is entering data for the first time (i.e. `data_input` is empty) then what you describe is not how textareas behave.

Comment: Does it line break and start from the beginning or is that in the middle as well?

Comment: @slime it does not line break, the cursor always appears on the first row but in the middle of the first row (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsbin.com/juwamigupo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I found a solution, I changed the Textarea tag the Input tag and called the php function in the value attributes and all works fine. Thank you so much for your help!